# Whose contact information should I provide in the cover letter when submitting a paper to a journal?

Tags: paper-submission

I am planning to submit a paper to a journal. Journals require a cover letter.  So, I wrote a brief introduction to my paper and some reasons for its publication.

After I looked at a few templates, I found that many cover letters had the contact information of the corresponding author at the end.
The corresponding author of this paper is my advisor. But he's very busy and I'm worried he might not be able to check his emails in time.

I am the first author of this paper. Can I leave both of our contact information at the end of the cover letter?

Comment: Has your advisor told you that he is (should be) the corresponding author? That's a job for the person who will actually read and respond to queries about the paper. Ask him if he wants that job or thinks you should do it.

Comment: In our school, tutors must be corresponding authors. Otherwise the thesis will not count when judging graduation requirements. My mentor took on a lot of administrative duties and he didn't always have the time.

Comment: Will you submit the paper? Then you will usually receive all communication from the journal during the whole submission process provided you will give your contact data in the submission system of the journal. Nobody will extract any e-mail address from the cover letter.

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If your advisor has set themself as corresponding author, then they have taken responsibility for actually *corresponding*. I worry that many people think of corresponding author as an honor of some kind rather than a job. Perhaps you are a better choice for corresponding author if you are the primary author of the work with the most to lose if things go wrong.

But that is a conversation you need to have with your advisor.

But it is probably a mistake to suggest that Alice is the corresponding author but you should *really* correspond with Bob instead.